# How to respond to Function Key input (Android)?

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I'm working with a terminal that is controlled by numbers and function keys (F1-F8). I'm required to go to a certain activity when F2 is pressed, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Starting a new intent on keycode F2 does not seem to work - the emulator isn't even recognize that I am pressing a button. Can anyone help?

Comment: Test on the actual terminal. Override `onKeyDown()` in some activity, press F2, and see what keycode gets generated. Proceed from there. For all you know, this terminal has mapped F2 to `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY`.

Comment: I've tried that - pressing the '2' key prints out keycode 9, and most other keys print out their own key codes. Pressing F2 (or any other function key) doesn't work, though. Nothing happens.

Comment: ::shrug:: You would have to talk to the manufacturer, I guess.